# Datastage Sortstage cluster key change vs key change

Tags: sorting, etl, datastage

According to IBM's documentation for Sort Stage:

> Create cluster key change column
>
> This property appears for sort type DataStage and is optional. It is set False by default. If set True it tells the Sort stage to create the column clusterKeyChange in each output record. **The clusterKeyChange column is set to 1 for the first record in each group where groups are defined by using a Sort Key Mode of Don't Sort (Previously Sorted) or Don't Sort (Previously Grouped)**. Subsequent records in the group have the clusterKeyChange column set to 0.

> Create key change column
>
> This property appears for sort type DataStage and is optional. It is set False by default. If set True it tells the Sort stage to create the column KeyChange in each output record. **The KeyChange column is set to 1 for the first record in each group where the value of the sort key changes**. Subsequent records in the group have the KeyChange column set to 0.

Those two options sound very similar to me.

1. When should I use which option?
2. How does the end result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the clusterKeyChange if you got Don't Sort columns and you want them to be considered - like when you grouped / sorted it before.
   The Key change column is more often used.
2. The result is an additional column showing 0 or 1 - 1 in case of a change - so the first row of a series of identical key vaues is marked to do some extra logic usually in a transformer.

Hint: Note that there is a transformer functionality that could be very useful as well LastRowInGroup which lets you react (i.E. reset values etc.) before you will receive a new value in the transformer. So this function might replace the sort stage option above but it needs sorted input to the transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's basically the same thing, but you might find situations where you need to use the cluster key change function so you can cascade the key changes.

For example, if you get year-to-date data containing several values per day and you want to calculate a sum for every day but also a sum for every month, you could then use the key change information on each new day and the cluster key change on each new month. *(Or was it vice versa? Just try what fits.)* Since the change singnal comes with every first row of a group, you might just want to collect the sum by adding values onto a sum-variable and as soon as you hit a `KeyChange=1` value, you reset your sum-variable to zero before adding the current value to the new group.